# C# Video Player Component with Stream Access for Decryption

Tags: c#, windows, video, mono, components

I am searching for a video player component (windows), usable in .Net (C#). What is required, is an access to the underlying stream, because parts of the video should be decrypted on the fly, and the decrypted video should never be stored on the hard disk. Ideally, it should also be portable for Linux and Mac.

Anyone knows some good video components featuring the requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two solutions for the problem, since I could not find a component flexible enough.

Here are the solutions:
 1. A custom video player, composed of demux+decode and a rendering (to directx or opengl for example).
 2. A virtual hard disk with a decryption layer, we implemented this solution, based on dokan vhdd driver.